# How to import Nightmarejs into angular-cli component

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, nightmare

I'm going to make GUI **scraper** with Electron & Nightmare.
However when I use just plain html/js as described in Electron quickstart, all works well.
But I'd like to make Electron app nicely by using Anugular2(angular-cli webpack).
I created project `ng new Scraper` then made some routes for components e.g. `HomeComponent`, `SettingsComponent`.
I installed nightmare in angular project folder by `npm install --save nightmare`
and I would like import it in `SettingsComponent` like:

```
import {Nightmare} from 'nightmare';
```

and use it like:

```
ngOnInit{
  this.nightmare = new Nightmare({
    show: true,
    electronPath: require('node_modules/electron')
  })
}
```

What have I tryied:

1. in index.html including

`<script src="node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js"></script>`

2. then in my component

```
declare var Nightmare: any;
```

3. ngOnInit(){

   this.nightmare = new Nightmare({})
4. Gettings errors about missing other js files inside `node_modules/nightmare/lib/*.js`

CODE:

```
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scrape</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/semantic.min.css">
  <script src="assets/require.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>

component:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var require: any;
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
@Component({
  selector: 'app-work',
  templateUrl: './work.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./work.component.css']
})
export class WorkComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

error:

```
Failed to compile.

./~/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Scrape\node_modules\nightmare\lib'
 @ ./~/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js 18:11-35
 @ ./src/app/work/work.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

It is possible to interact with Angular2/Nightmare inside Electron App?